# Loops for filtering football matches

Tags: r, loops

i am trying to write a loop which will filter the HomeTeam playing with AwayTeam by particular team. So in the end i can have a column which will tell me the number of matches won/lost/draw when a particular team played against the AwayTeam in the past. So the original data set looks like this:

```
         Date   HomeTeam   AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG   FTR  Draw  Lost   Win 
        (chr)      (chr)      (chr) (int) (int) (chr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)  
1 17/08/2002  Blackburn Sunderland     0     0     D     1     0     0      
2 17/08/2002   Charlton    Chelsea     2     3     A     0     1     0      
3 17/08/2002    Everton  Tottenham     2     2     D     1     0     0      
4 17/08/2002     Fulham     Bolton     4     1     H     0     0     1      
5 17/08/2002      Leeds   Man City     3     0     H     0     0     1      
6 17/08/2002 Man United  West Brom     1     0     H     0     0     1
```

i have written this code first:

```
arsenal <- football %>% 
  select(1:10) %>% 
  filter(football$HomeTeam == "Arsenal" & football$AwayTeam == "Birmingham" & Date >= 17/08/2002)
birmingham <- football %>% 
  select(Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG, FTAG, FTR) %>% 
  filter(football$HomeTeam == "Birmingham" & football$AwayTeam == "Arsenal" & Date >= 17/08/2002)
```

It produced the following:

```
        Date HomeTeam   AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG   FTR  Draw  Lost   Win 
       (chr)    (chr)      (chr) (int) (int) (chr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) 
1 18/08/2002  Arsenal Birmingham     2     0     H     0     0     1      
2   01/05/04  Arsenal Birmingham     0     0     D     1     0     0      
3   04/12/04  Arsenal Birmingham     3     0     H     0     0     1      
4   02/10/05  Arsenal Birmingham     1     0     H     0     0     1     
5   12/01/08  Arsenal Birmingham     1     1     D     1     0     0      
6   17/10/09  Arsenal Birmingham     3     1     H     0     0     1  
         Date   HomeTeam AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG   FTR
       (chr)      (chr)    (chr) (int) (int) (chr)
1 12/01/2003 Birmingham  Arsenal     0     4     A
2   22/11/03 Birmingham  Arsenal     0     3     A
3   15/05/05 Birmingham  Arsenal     2     1     H
4   04/02/06 Birmingham  Arsenal     0     2     A
5   23/02/08 Birmingham  Arsenal     2     2     D
6   27/03/10 Birmingham  Arsenal     1     1     D
```

So i would like to automate this process for all teams like in the example above. i have produced the following loop but it doesnt work:

```
list_of_teams <- c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Manchester City", "Liverpool")
for(i in 1:length(list_of_teams)){ football_1 <- football %>% 
    select(1:10) %>% 
    filter(football$HomeTeam == list_of_teams[i] & football$AwayTeam == list_of_teams[i+1])
for(j in 1:length(list_of_teams[-i])){
    football$HomeTeam == list_of_teams[j] & football$AwayTeam == list_of_teams[-i]
    print(c(list_of_teams[[i]], list_of_teams[-i][[j]]))
  }
}
```

The plan was to create the empty dataframe and then based on what loop produces it will store it there. However, eventually it will store only the teams which are in list_of_teams variable initially created.
Question is: why does the loop ignore/or doesnt do selection of the columns 1:10 and filter the HomeTeam and AwayTeam accordingly and how we can solve this problem?
Thank u in advance, i am new to R and programming any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of data frames containing all matches per unique `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` ?

Comment: I wonder if you can get to your final aim  (*tell me the number of matches won/lost/draw when a particular team played against the AwayTeam*) in one step: `aggregate(cbind(Draw, Lost, Win) ~ HomeTeam + AwayTeam, data=dat, sum)`